# Alternative ways for expressing a narrow victory

Tags: word-choice, idioms, vocabulary, translation

I am a Czech interpreter working with English. Just recently during a conference a "funny" guy tried to use elaborative Czech idiom with a twist. We often say *to win by breast* instead of *win by a nose*. He said:

> We won by breast of a Korean woman.

It sounds terrible on an official conference but we are in the Czech Republic, the *me too* movement still has a long way to go.

He insisted on me translating for him. Is there any way to use *win by a nose* with a twist? Let me know please. Thanks.

Comment: Was the speaker who said "we won" himself Korean?

Comment: Is the reference to a Koream woman's breasts idiomatic in Czech? I assume from your post it is. I find that randomness very interesting. Why Korean?

Comment: @L.Moneta - The Czech idiom translates literally as "by a breast", per the querent. The "twist" of the "Korean woman" is not part of the idiom; it is an attempt (which, as far as I am concerned, failed) to both be funny and to indicate that the margin was _very_ slim - it plays to the stereotype that Korean women (women from _most_ "Far Eastern" cultures, in fact) have noticeably smaller pectoral adipose deposits than women from most European cultures.

Comment: Just to clarify your question:  You're asking if there is any way to  translate the Czech idiom "win by a breast" into English without causing offense?  Or, if not, then to substitute a "funny" (but inoffensive) idiom with the same meaning?

Comment: "Won by a nose" is used literally in horse racing.  (It might also be used in dog racing.)  Whereas in human track-and-field, races are determined by which runner's chest starts to cross the finish line first.  Thus the original poster's "win by a breast" has a literal meaning for human races.  (But "win by a breast" is not idiomatic in American English.)

Comment: Are you looking for a phrase that's unoffensive but preserves the humor, something less offensive but still bawdy, something still offensive but not misogynistic, or something else?

Comment: won by the skin of our teeth..

Comment: I don't see the problem. Your job is to translate the intent of the speaker, not to translate idioms verbatim. So insert an appropriate English idiom with a similar meaning.
Obviously ethnic, religious observations and opinions should be left out of diplomatic speech.

Answer (score 3):

(This answer assumes you're looking for a diplomatic solution that downplays the offensiveness while preserving a sense of humor.)

**by a nose hair**

Although [*win by a nose*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/win+by+a+nose) is an standard English idiom, this suggestion is not.  But since there is a separate idiom, [*by a hair*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+a+hair) (also *by a whisker* or *by a hair's width/breadth*), your meaning of "even smaller than a narrow margin" would be understood along with the humorous intent.

**by the skin of a hen's tooth**

This also combines two existing English idioms for effect.
[*By the skin of one's teeth*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/by+the+skin+of+teeth) means to barely succeed and further implies that luck was involved.
[*As scarce as hen's teeth*](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/scarce+as+hen%27s+teeth) refers to something extremely rare in a stereotypically country way.

N.B. Although [mixed metaphors](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mixed+metaphor) are normally to be avoided, their deliberate choice here is the point of the joke.  One danger of combining idioms like this is that it may confuse language learners, who may not notice the humor and take the intended joke as a common phrase in English.

Answer (score 2):

The implication of the “funny” statement is that the win was by even less than the normal very close win (“by a nose”). In English, that can sometimes be expressed as “winning in a [photo finish](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/photo%20finish)” (link is to Merriam-Webster, online), implying that the victory was so close that one would have to closely examine a picture of the actual finish to determine exactly who won.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be a pun: **"It was a clothes call."**

The saying is normally "It was a **close** call," but replacing that with **clothes** gives it a humorous twist. The two words are pronounced similarly (and often identically, even though they shouldn't be), and the race could have been won "by the difference in the thickness of worn clothing."

Comment: The pun only works in writing, it's a clever one, but in speech hardly any one would get it.

Answer (score 1):

You could refer to the team that came in second:

> We just managed to nip the {____} team.
>
> We nipped the {___}.

Comment: Given the context, _nip_ is a questionable choice. It's even **more** offensive as a [racial slur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nip).

Comment: The translation attempted to preserve some of the original's offensiveness.

Comment: I thought as much.  But by not making that explicit, this answer could cause problems for someone unaware of the history of the word.

Comment: Maybe you should stand guard.

Comment: I'll assume good faith here and have proposed an edit incorporating your point.

Comment: That's not the particular offensiveness I was attempting to preserve.

Comment: All the more reason to elaborate—perhaps "This translation attempts to preserve some of the original's offensiveness by making a pun on the word *nipple*. The word *nip* also has a history on its own as an [ethnic slur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nip)."

Comment: I really don't think anyone's in danger here, and I don't feel the need to explain the pun.